# How to prepare field for display in Drupal

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7

I'm having a problem with picture module and loading of lists. So my structure is content type with some fields one of them is image set to display picture.

On another page I wan't to display 2 objects of that content type. So I select it from the database and preprocess fields. With normal fields it's ok since i only need theirs value, but with picture I need all other data like breakpoints, theme.
Basicly for image I get that:

```
array (size=1)
  'und' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=18)
          'fid' => string '3023' (length=4)
          'uid' => string '1' (length=1)
          'filename' => string 'profile_picture.jpg' (length=19)
          'uri' => string 'public://profile_picture.jpg' (length=28)
          'filemime' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
          'filesize' => string '325835' (length=6)
          'status' => string '1' (length=1)
          'timestamp' => string '1421745203' (length=10)
          'type' => string 'image' (length=5)
          'uuid' => string '59484070-9a95-42fb-8b2a-594e5d3a7483' (length=36)
          'field_file_image_alt_text' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
          'field_file_image_title_text' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
          'rdf_mapping' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
          'metadata' => 
            array (size=2)
              'height' => int 500
              'width' => int 400
          'alt' => string '' (length=0)
          'title' => string '' (length=0)
          'width' => string '400' (length=3)
          'height' => string '500' (length=3)
```

And I need that:

```
'#theme' => string 'picture_formatter' (length=17)
  '#attached' => 
    array (size=1)
      'library' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string 'picture' (length=7)
              1 => string 'picturefill_head' (length=16)
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string 'picture' (length=7)
              1 => string 'picturefill' (length=11)
          2 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string 'picture' (length=7)
              1 => string 'picture.ajax' (length=12)
  '#item' => 
    array (size=18)
      'fid' => string '3023' (length=4)
      'uid' => string '1' (length=1)
      'filename' => string 'profile_picture.jpg' (length=19)
      'uri' => string 'public://profile_picture.jpg' (length=28)
      'filemime' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'filesize' => string '325835' (length=6)
      'status' => string '1' (length=1)
      'timestamp' => string '1421745203' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'image' (length=5)
      'uuid' => string '59484070-9a95-42fb-8b2a-594e5d3a7483' (length=36)
      'field_file_image_alt_text' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'field_file_image_title_text' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'rdf_mapping' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'metadata' => 
        array (size=2)
          'height' => int 500
          'width' => int 400
      'alt' => string '' (length=0)
      'title' => string '' (length=0)
      'width' => string '400' (length=3)
      'height' => string '500' (length=3)
  '#image_style' => string 'large_custom_user_mobile_1x' (length=27)
  '#breakpoints' => 
    array (size=5)
      'custom.user.ultra_wide' => 
        array (size=1)
          '1x' => 
            array (size=2)
              'mapping_type' => string 'image_style' (length=11)
              'image_style' => string 'large_custom_user_ultra_wide_1x' (length=31)
      'custom.user.wide' => 
        array (size=1)
          '1x' => 
            array (size=2)
              'mapping_type' => string 'image_style' (length=11)
              'image_style' => string 'large_custom_user_wide_1x' (length=25)
      'custom.user.normal' => 
        array (size=1)
          '1x' => 
            array (size=2)
              'mapping_type' => string 'image_style' (length=11)
              'image_style' => string 'large_custom_user_normal_1x' (length=27)
      'custom.user.narrow' => 
        array (size=1)
          '1x' => 
            array (size=2)
              'mapping_type' => string 'image_style' (length=11)
              'image_style' => string 'large_custom_user_narrow_1x' (length=27)
      'custom.user.mobile' => 
        array (size=1)
          '1x' => 
            array (size=2)
              'mapping_type' => string 'image_style' (length=11)
              'image_style' => string 'large_custom_user_mobile_1x' (length=27)
  '#path' => string '' (length=0)
  '#colorbox_group' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '#colorbox_image_style' => string '' (length=0)
```

So the question is how to prepare field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is [field_view_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7). This function will invoke internally [hook_field_formatter_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7). The picture module [implements this hook](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/picture/tree/picture.module?id=9aa9903121b54dd43523e66e1e1e5bebf4d5a782#n747), and depending on the `$display` parameter it will internally call one of the provided display functions.

Based on the desired output you requested, you should pass `picture` as display parameter, in order to invoke [picture_field_formatter_picture_view()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/picture/tree/picture.module?id=9aa9903121b54dd43523e66e1e1e5bebf4d5a782#n757) which seems to return the appropriate renderable array.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I tried like that: field_view_field("my_content_type", $node, "field_image"); but i get empty array as return. I get $node with node_load(nid).

Comment: Don't use the content type as the first parameter, just pass 'node' and it should work.
    `$node = node_load(336);
    field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_author');`

Comment: I kinda make it work with field_view_field("node", $node, "field_image", array('type' => 'picture')); It's not exactly the same but it works!